# How to solve this double summation with a variable stopping point?

Tags: summation

I know how to solve basic double summations but, i have trouble with this one, specifically I don't know how to begin since the end point of the inner summation is not an independent value.
$$
\Sigma^4_{i=1}\Sigma^i_{j=1} (ij-1)\,
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $$\sum_{j=1}^11(j-1)+\sum_{j=1}^2(2j-1)+\sum_{j=1}^3(3j-1)+\sum_{j=1}^4(4j-1)=$$
$$=1+2(1+2)+3(1+2+3)+4(1+2+3+4)-1-2-3-4=55$$

Comment: So whenever I have double summations of this kind, i just split it as many summations as the max value of the inner summation end point, and then substitute the "i" with the end point of the new summation? Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, of course! And you can make the same thing in the general case.